# How to restrict selecting folder for UIDocumentPickerViewController while multiple select option

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have integrated `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in application. I can access the files from Files app. Need to restrict folder selection from drive and cloud as well.

When I enable multiple file "Select" option using "allowsMultipleSelection". when user select "Select" option in documentPickerViewController, I don't want to allow user to select folder.

How do I restrict user to select "Folder"?.

Code used to launch Files app is:

```
let documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.data"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
documentPicker.delegate = self
documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
})
```

Comment: how you initiate UIDocumentPickerViewController ?

Comment: add the code of UIDocumentPickerViewController present and allocate

Answer (score 2):

You can not restrict folder selection however you can ignore selected folder URL.

- There will "/" character with end of each folder url, So you can compare it by using below code and skip it.
  **Swift 4**

  ```
  func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
      var arrFilesURL = [URL]()
      arrFilesURL = urls.filter { (url) -> Bool in
          return url.absoluteString.last != "/"
      }
      controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
  ```

Comment: This work for folder if it is in iCloud storage. But if user select Folder from Google drive, didPickDocumentsAt not getting called instead documentPickerWasCancelled delegate is called.

Comment: In that case you need to mention folder selection from drive, cloud as well.